# jQuery mobile - show filp toggle switch vertical

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am new to jquery mobile and css. I am using 1.3.1 version of it. I wish to show the flip toggle switch vertical. By default it is horizontal. Is there some way using css to achieve this?

Comment: Please show the HTML and jQuery you're using to create this toggle switch; having looked at your profile page it seems you've been active here on Stack Overflow long enough that you should have known to include the (relevant) code, without reminders.

Comment: You should update to 1.9.x

Comment: No additional code is needed here. Toggle switch is standard jQuery Mobile widget and Supereme just want to know how to make it vertical.

Comment: @Gajotres: great, but since I, and presumably some others, don't work with jQuery mobile I have no idea how the switches are created. Or what HTML is used to implement them, I was hoping to avoid having to read through the API in order to potentially provide assistance, since, with the jQuery, it'd be easy enough to look up the specific widgets/methods.

Comment: Given the lack of input, and an implicit lack of interest, I'm voting to close, as not constructive.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment (Jquery Mobile 1.4.2) there isn't a vertical flipswitch in the demo

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/flipswitch/

And there is nothing in the API also

https://api.jquerymobile.com/flipswitch/

But you could use a jqxSwitchButton from jqwidgets, look at the sample

https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxbutton/jquery-button-getting-started.htm#jquerysample10